# Python output on Webserver REALTIME

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have a Raspberry Pi with an I2C temperature sensor.

Python code:

```
import board
import adafruit_mlx90614
import time

i2c = board.I2C()
mlx = adafruit_mlx90614.MLX90614(i2c)
while True:
    print("Object Temp: ", mlx.object_temperature)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Object Temp:  21.89
Object Temp:  22.73
Object Temp:  27.31
```

It's working fine. But how can I make the output shown on the local webserver?
REALTIME, no page refreshing?
Just like a text. Nothing fancy.

Thanks

Comment: This is a complex task. You will need 1) Python Webserver (Django/Flask) for API call that returns temperature value, 2) Javascript code that constantly makes the API call and updates the text of <div> tag, 3) Html code with a single <div> tag whose text will be updated by javascript. This is an interesting & totally doable thing, but it will take 'little' more effort than just printing out in the terminal!

Answer (score 4):

We will first need to set up a python web server, I chose to use Flask here. Second, we need to create an HTML file with a script that will update the data every few seconds (I chose 5 seconds here). So just make a new file called index.html in a new directory called /templates. Then just add the following html in the index.html file.

PS: You can cahnge that 5000 value in the setInterval function in the script, just make sure you count by the thousands, like 3 seconds would be 3000.

Python Code:

```
import board
import adafruit_mlx90614
import time

i2c = board.I2C()
mlx = adafruit_mlx90614.MLX90614(i2c)

from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/temp')
def getTemp():
    return str(mlx.object_temperature)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="temp">Object Temp: 0</p>
<script>
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='http://localhost:5000/temp';

function checkTemp(){
   Http.open("GET", url);
   Http.send();
  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    document.querySelector("#temp").innerHTML = "Object Temp: " + Http.responseText;
  }
}

setInterval(checkTemp, 5000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfect, that's working, just needed to change 'return str(mlx.object_temperature)' to string as it doesn't work with float, which's fine, but unfortunately, it's not refreshing itself at all

Comment: Now? I edited the setInterval function, i switched the parameters around, my javascript is a bit rusty thesse days but this should work now after i edited it

Comment: Unfortunately, still not refreshing

Comment: Could you try visit http://localhost:5000/temp ? Does it show the temperature when you refresh it? The code seems to work on my machine after I copied the new edited version, are you absolute sure that its this "setInterval(checkTemp, 5000);" and not "setInterval(5000, checkTemp);" in your code?

Comment: Yes, when I manually refresh the page, it's showing me new values each time. But need to do that manually. Tried both "checkTemp" versions.

Comment: So just to confirm, does the http://localhost:5000/ just show "Object Temp: 0" after every 5 seconds? Could you maybe also check the console errors on that page?

Comment: I had to change to `const url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/temp';` under macOS, else `Http.responseText` was empty.